A relation between the Lemniscate and Squircle
There is a very nice YouTube video which illustrates a remarkable relation between areas of sectors of the squircle $x^4+y^4 = 1$ and arc lengths of segments of the lemniscate $(x^2 + y^2)^2 = x^2 - y^2$. It is derivable by elementary means as shown here.
This relation can be formulated as follows in terms of lemniscate and squircular versions of sine and cosine:
$$ 
\operatorname{cl}(\sqrt{2}t) = \frac{\cos_4^2(t)-\sin_4^2(t)}{\cos_4^2(t)+\sin_4^2(t)}.
$$
Has anyone seen this precise formulation (and elementary proof) before? As I point out in Remark 4 of that article, this relation can also be derived (in a somewhat convoluted way) from relations between lemniscate elliptic functions and hyperbolic versions of these functions.
There are a couple of reasons I am interested in finding what if any references there are to this relation. One reason is that I have added a link to this video to the Wikipedia article "Lemniscate elliptic functions". The main editor of this article is worried that this relation and other relations in the section on hyperbolic elliptic functions are thinly sourced and may violate the Wikipedia policies on "Reliable sources" and "No original research" and hence may be subject to deletion.
Another reason is that I am planning to add this to an undergraduate analysis book I am writing (which already has a section on lemniscate elliptic functions) and would like to add any references for further reading. (Also I welcome any comments on the book.)

I just realized that the Siegel technique can be used to provide an alternative proof of the relation shown in the YouTube video. The relation in that video can be written as
$\int_{R^2}^1\frac{dr}{\sqrt{1-r^4}}=\sqrt{2}\int_0^T\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}},\quad T=\sqrt{\frac{1-R^2}{1+R^2}},$
and these two integrals are related by the substitution  $t=\sqrt{\frac{1-r}{1+r}}$.

I haven't gotten any responses for my reference request. However I did find a kind of reference on my own. I found that in his lecture notes "Topics on Complex Function Theory" volume 1, that C. L. Siegel, in his discussion of Fagnano's doubling formula for arcs of the lemniscate, derives the following relation:
$\int_0^R\frac{dr}{\sqrt{1-r^4}}=\sqrt{2}\int_0^T\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}},\quad R=\frac{\sqrt{2}\,T}{\sqrt{1+T^4}}.$
This implicitly relates areas of squircle sectors (the integral on the right) to the arc length of segments of the lemniscate (integral on the left).  This is a different relation than the one I posted above. However these results are strongly related and in fact Siegel's calculation provides an alternative proof of the above relation.
In the meantime I have gotten in touch with Muthu Veerappan R., the author of the above mentioned YouTube video, and we have written a joint paper, which we plan to submit for publication. I have posted a preprint on arxiv.org at the following link. I welcome any comments or further discussion.  You can leave comments here or at this experimental comment interface for arxiv articles.
